# Laravel Route [blood-camp] not defined exception

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I'm getting this error even though the route is defined

`Route [blood-camp] not defined. (View: C:\wamp64\www\blood-donation\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)`

web.php file

```
`Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home.root');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/user', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index'])->name('user');



Route::resource('blood-camp', BloodCampController::class);

Route::resource('donor', DonorController::class);

Route::resource('camp-schedule', CampScheduleController::class);`
```

app.blade.php

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
 <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('blood-camp') }}" role="button" >
                                {{ __('Camps') }}
</a>
</li>
```

controller class

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class BloodCampController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

public function index()
    {        
        return view('blood_camp.index', ['camps' =>        DB::table('blood_camps')->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->paginate(10)]);
    }

//all the other resources are there...

}
```

route:list

There is no duplicate route

[image]

I have tried all the suggested ways including changing path names, cache clearing, private window, restarting server, but I'm still getting this error and no way to go further developments.

It first occurred when I adding new route called camp, I changed the name to blood-camp but no luck, now it throw exceptions for the other routes as well. Can someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is no route with that **name**. `{{ route('blood-camp') }}` points to a **named** route, did you mean `{{ url('blood-camp') }}` to point to an URL?

Comment: Yep! your are correct. It is due to using `route()` instead of `url()`. What is the difference between them?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-route and https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-url should help

Comment: However, that was not the case,  Route::resource() doesn't generate a default route for 'blood-camp'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the result of your `route:list` shows, you dont have a route with the alias `blood-camp`.

What you have as alias is `blood-camp.index`, `blood-camp.store`....

To generate the link of the ressources listing use:

By path/url

```
{{ url('blood-camp') }}
```

Or by alias

```
{{ route('blood-camp.index') }}
```

Comment: Because of I'm using `Route::resource` , those alias are auto created.

Comment: @ErangaPerera exactly so use `{{ route('blood-camp.index') }}` to list the ressource or `{{ url('blood-camp') }}`

Comment: It took me time to understand the difference between those two function. To use the route('blood-camp.something') function there should be a name route as it is. Thanks!